# ¿como le sumo un numero a cada elemento de un array?

Tags: javascript, array, bucle-for, function

[image: esto es lo que me piden]

> este es mi codigo:

```
function mostrarSiguiente (array, suma){ 
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { 
        var siguiente = array[i] + suma;
        console.log(siguiente);
    }
}

mostrarSiguiente([0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20],1);
```

> pero la consola me devuelve esto:

*1
3
5
7
9
11
13
15
17
19
21
1
3
5
7
9
11
13
15
17
19
21

=> undefined*

> ¿a que se debe que repita el procedimiento dos veces y porque me sale un undefined al final? ¿me podrían decir que error tengo?

Comment: Tu código esta bien, concretamente este trozo de código solo imprime en consola una vez. Asegúrate de no estar llamando al método en otro lado.

Comment: tenes razón bro, el código esta bien. Lo que pasa es que yo estaba practicando con la consola de Mumuki y me devolvía eso, después probé con la del chrome y si me da bien como vos decís, gracias!! y ya saben gente si están estudiando desde Mumuki no confíen en la consola de Mumuki jaja.

Comment: Genial entonces, un saludo

Comment: igualmente! amigo